# How to get a Password reset link from Email by Java API in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I am trying to get password reset link which is sent to email

```
System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());
System.out.println("link: " + message.getDescription());
```

**Ouput:**

Email Number 2

Subject: Welcome to Application

From: abc xyz

Text: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@185d8b6

link: null

Comment: How do you get your `message` and why do you expect getting link by calling `getDescription()`?

Comment: iam using this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417037/reading-email-from-gmail-is-not-working

Comment: getDescription() will return mail content?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `getContent()` you get the object of  `javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart` class. You cannot simply take a text from there because the content might contain text, video, images, files, and so on.

You should parse your content down by parts (that might be not trivial since there might be a tree structure) and fetch data from there basing on each particular part mime type.

Check [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html) for details. The basic approach is to:

1. Invoke `getContent()`. Check if returned content is a multipart. If yes,
2. Invoke `getCount()` on received object to find the number of parts in your multipart
3. Handle all BodyParts. Check class of what is returned by `getContent()`. If it is a MultiPart, go to step 2
4. If it is not, call `getContentType()` and process the item according to the returned type.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the message body, it will be a multipart message.  Basically, each email server is different as to how they store their messages.  You need to build a parser loops through all body parts and which for each message body part's type.  And then decodes that type into something you can read.

Comment: can u provide one example?